# The reason to be waitlisted in a PhD position application

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

What can be the possible reasons to be not accepted to a PhD program if you are a first author in the journal with high impact factor , have a work experience and graduated with honors from the top university.
Some candidates that were accepted don’t have the Master diploma and no publications. My field is bioinformatics, majority of candidates were wet labs.
There were a selection with interviews but there were no problems or questions that were not answered by me.
The committee consisted of people more familiar with the others candidate topics than mine, moreover none of a jury had a computational lab. They came to a conclusion that bioinformatics just analyze the data of a project that the wet lab part designed, which is not true. All of that may be of course because of the my presentation but the point is that they didn’t give a feedback so I cannot improve from that and that’s why I am asking a question here.
Important to note that I had a knowledge of the questions on the wet lab that were asked which out of the bioinformatician scope.
I’ve asked for a feedback and the answer was: everything was good

Comment: No way for anyone but them to answer this. Likely there were many qualified candidates. Likely some met certain needs better than others. Good that you were waitlisted, not rejected.

Comment: "My field is bioinformatics, majority of candidates were wet labs" - maybe the admissions committee prefers.people with wet lab experience. Is that wrong? Why? You aren't guaranteed a job by meeting all the expectations, you have to be the best (or top N) candidate. It's not their job to help you improve, their job is to pick the candidates they think will be most successful. Perhaps you should have applied to other places that would have a better view of your experience. Some of that is luck of who makes the decisions.

Comment: Please do not deface your question, even if it is closed. Rather try to [edit] it to address the issues that led to closure (without invalidating most of the answers). Even if you cannot edit it, others might or the question could still serve as a sign post.

Answer (score 3):

In general waitlists mean they think they have better candidates than you, but you're competitive enough that if one of the other candidates decline, they'll choose you instead. Your application isn't declined, it's just that they don't consider it as strong as the other candidates' application. You might think your application is stronger, but your judgment does not matter here, only theirs does.

(But do keep in mind that lots of things are assessed in a PhD application, beyond publications, work experience, and grades; their relative weights might be different as well.)

Answer (score 2):

Good performance in an interview is more than just "answering all the questions". How you answer matters a lot: do you display intellectual maturity and evidence of deeper understanding? Often, a candidate who doesn't know the answer to a technical question but who is able to give a logically-reasoned suggestion for what the answer *might* be is more attractive than a candidate who just seems to have memorised a textbook.

Also, it is often difficult to be wholly objective about ranking candidates. Person A has more C++ experience than Person B; but person B has taken more classes on differential equations. Who is 'better'? Eventually it just comes down to a judgement call about who the interviewers feel is best-suited to the position.

Comment: So is someone who recognizes the boundaries of their understanding and doesn't try to invent understanding on the spot. That might be a good strategy for a standardized test but isn't going to fly in a manuscript.

Answer (score 1):

Departments continuously look at in what sub-sub-fields they want to grow. This also means a choice of where they do not want to grow. The internal politics of that department could result in the choice that computational biology is not a priority, and the fact that no person in the committee has a computational lab *could*  be an indication of that. In that case, you may or may not be a wonderful computational biologist, but if they are not looking for computational biologists, then it does not matter how many publications you have. You are in that case not the right person for that job.

In the end this is all speculation. If you want to know, you have to ask them. They may or may not answer.